# Entity Framework does the data type effect the behavior of PropertyConfiguration methods?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Assuming

```
public int? Count { get; set; }
```

Are the following two statements equal?

```
Property(v => v.Count).HasColumnName("count");
Property(v => v.Count).HasColumnName("count").IsOptional();
```

Does this also hold true for complex data types, say:

```
public Foo Bar { get; set; }

Property(v => v.Prop1).HasColumnName("prop1");
Property(v => v.Prop1).HasColumnName("prop1").IsOptional();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case, yes, the two statements are equal in terms they would produce the same DDL.

In the second case, if `Foo` is a complex type, it means that `Bar` is a navigation property. And you should treat navigation properties differently in configuration, eg:

```
HasRequired(x => x.Bar).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.BarId)
```

or

```
HasOptional(x => x.Bar).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.BarId)
```

depending on intended relationship.